# Create Line Items with Modifiers Through Square Connect API

Tags: square-connect

I want to create an order on a Square POS (on an iPad) for an item with modifiers (eg: a coffee with soy milk). I want the item to be added to the "Current Sale" area, so the user has to press the "Charge" button. Is this possible, and if so how?

I've looked at both the V2 API and the POS API, and can't see how to create orders with line items with modifiers. Is there a way?
I also suspect that despite the POS API going through the iPad APP (via URL schemes), it won't result in the user interface of Square popping up and the Current Sale being populated. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot currently inject orders into the Point of Sale app, but it is feedback we are listening to and working on addressing.

You can use the Point of Sale app to make charges and then update the item inventory amounts with the REST endpoints, however the items will not be attached to the sale.